# Add to home screen button closes browser / does not add to home screen

Tags: iphone, ios

I've recently come across an issue when adding a link to home screen on iOS 12 ( Safari browser ). Once I click the button to add it will close the browser and do nothing. I've not seen much detail on this online and am not sure if apple has changed something or not. any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is very difficult to understand..."Add to home screen button?"  What does that mean?  "Adding a link to the home screen?"  I'm not understanding what you're trying to do.  Can you please clarify or post an example?

Comment: I've uploaded an image. when on safari you can add the website to your homescreen. after clicking add it will close and not add to homescreen.